# How do I convert csv data into bar chart?

Tags: python, csv, bar-chart

I have already done a line plot using the csv data and import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
charge, total and year have already been append by rows.
[image: csv table]

My code

```
plt.plot(year, charge, '-g', label = 'Chargeable Income')
plt.plot(year, total, '-r', label = 'Total Income')
plt.title('Chargeable and Total Income VS Year')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('(S$)')

plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This is how the current line plot looks like:

[image: this is how the current line plot looks like]

How do I code so that it becomes a bar chart like this:
[image: this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [example](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) in the matplotlib site and you can find another approach of your issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369681/how-to-plot-bar-graphs-with-same-x-coordinates-side-by-side-dodged). Basically, you just shift the x values by width. Here is the relevant bit:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# create sample data as np.array in the provided format year | chargeable | total
arr = np.array([[2017, 375873, 78833], [2018, 783893, 98288]])

ind = np.arange(arr.shape[0])  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, arr[:, 2], width, color='royalblue')

rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, arr[:, 1], width, color='seagreen')

# add some
ax.set_ylabel('(S$)')
ax.set_ylabel('Year')
ax.set_title('Chargeable and Total Income VS Year')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width / 2)
ax.set_xticklabels( arr[:, 0] )

ax.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Chargeable Income', 'Total Income') )

plt.show()
```

Comment: instead of typing "arr = np.array([[2017, 375873, 78833], [2018, 783893, 98288]])" is there any other way to get the number from the csv data since i have already imported csv and also appended the year, charge and total income?

Comment: which number do you mean? Do you mean how you can access e.g. a specific line in your imported csv data or loading values without importing the csv file? Could you define your question more precisely?

Comment: I'll try to explain clearer. So let's say I want to display "chargeable" and "total income" VS "Years" as a bar chart, which means that I need to tell the code what are the values for each of them.  Instead of manually type "2017, 375873, 78833" and other years, is there any other way to retrieve the data straightaway and display it? I don't wish to type every value for each year. I have already assigned all values of Year, Total_Income and Chargeable_Income as year, total and charge in my code.

Comment: @Jon If your data is in a [.csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) or [.xlsx](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) file format (or other tabular formats) you can easily import them into python as an array.

Comment: Oh yes how do i do that

Comment: Just click on the attached links in the previous comment :)