# Display multiple columns side by side in bar plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below sample data is not the exact data which I am using, it is just a data with random values.

Sample data:

| Region | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| India | 25 | 12 |
| Australia | 18 | 05 |
| USA | 77 | 56 |
| Ghana | 28 | 13 |
| France | 35 | 41 |
| UK | 50 | 72 |
| Germany | 44 | 12 |
| Spain | 10 | 16 |
| Russia | 09 | 91 |

I want to create a bar plot comparing x and y columns of each region. And bar for x and y should be displayed side by side.

Code I used

```
plt.bar('Region', 'State_Fund_Accrual2016', data = df, color = 'green', label = "State fund Planned", alpha = 0.5)
plt.bar('Region', 'State_Fund_Release2016', data = df, color = 'red', label = "State fund Released", alpha = 0.5
plt.legend()
plt.xticks(rotation = 90, fontsize = 10)

plt.show
```

Below is the output which I am getting

[image]

Desired output:

I want my plot to look similar to the below image
[image]

Please suggest some method to get the desired output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot bar graphs with same X coordinates side by side ('dodged')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369681/how-to-plot-bar-graphs-with-same-x-coordinates-side-by-side-dodged)

Comment: Beside @IoaTzimas comment you can also find a similar answer if you are using `np.array` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68357753/how-do-i-convert-csv-data-into-bar-chart/68358263#68358263). But it seems like you're using DataFrame, in that case @tdy answer should do the work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it would be simplest to use [**`DataFrame.plot.bar()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) with `Region` as the index:

```py
df.set_index('Region').plot.bar()
```

[image: multibar output]